# How to write subscript text in game maker?

Tags: game-maker, gml

How can i type subscripts in text in game maker studio.
I want to type H2(g) where I want 2(g) be a subscript.

Answer (score 1):

Create two fonts. For example, `fnt_normal` with size 20 and `fnt_small` with size 10.

Create script called `draw_text_special`

```
/// draw_text_special(x, y, font, text)

var posx = argument0;
var posy = argument1;
var font = argument2;
var text = argument3;

draw_set_font(font);
var width = string_width(text);

draw_text(posx, posy, text);

return width;
```

Then use like this (in `Draw` event):

```
var posx = 10;
var posy = 50;

draw_set_halign(fa_left);
draw_set_valign(fa_bottom);

posx += draw_text_special(posx, posy, fnt_normal, "H");
posx += draw_text_special(posx, posy, fnt_small, "2(g)");
posx += draw_text_special(posx, posy, fnt_normal, "  Normal string");
posx += draw_text_special(posx, posy, fnt_small, "subscript string");
```